# Python moving average on web data

Tags: python

Relatively new to python so apologies if I ask a stupid question.

I just want to check if this is possible and if it is how complex.

I would like to calculate the moving average from share data on this web page

https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?a=&b=&c=&d=11&e=16&f=2015&g=d&s=LLOY.L%2C+&ql=1

Comment: You should download the page (try e.g. `urllib`), then you should parse the html (`BeautifulSoup` is good for that), then calculate the average (that part should be easy).

Comment: @zvone not quite sure if this is meant to be a scraping operation, but if so, that'd definitely work too :).

Comment: @N.Wouda  The question is unclear. OP did not really say what his problem is ;) I was in fact expecting his response to clarify the question.

Comment: @zvone eagerly awaiting the same here!

Comment: My aim is to calculate 2 moving averages from this data source. The print view would effectively just show; Lloyds - MA 10 £3.45, MA 30 £4.20

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code.

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = raw_input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
   # Look at the parts of a tag
   #calculate whatever you wanto
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?a=&b=&c=&d=11&e=16&f=2015&g=d&s=LLOY.L%2C+&ql=1"
html_contents = request.urlopen(url).read()

page = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, "html.parser")
el_list = page.find_all("span", {"id": "yfs_p43_lloy.l"})
print(el_list[0])
```

Comment: Thanks all for your comments and replies.